# How to interpret return value in Objectify save()

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Objectify's `save().entity(E entity).now()` method returns a the `Key<E>` of the saved `entity`, which is useful when saving a new entity for the first time. So far, so good.

However, it's not entirely clear what this method returns when saving an entity that was already present in datastore, or whether the return value can tell me anything about whether that write was successful.  Can I assume it *was* successful unless a `RuntimeException` is thrown, as per [these javadocs](http://docs.objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/git/apidocs/com/googlecode/objectify/Result.html)?  If so, is the true regardless of whether the write is inside a transaction?

Specifically, I'm reading, then modifying and saving two entities in an XG transaction using Objectify.  I'm currently checking the return value of the first save before saving the second, like this:

```
if(ofy().save().entity(entA).now() != null) {
    ofy().save().entity(entB).now();
}
```

Firstly, I guess the first thing is I should save these with one `ofy().save().entities(ent1, ent2).now()` call?

Secondly, is it even meaningful for me to check the return value of the `ofy().save().entity().now()` call:

1. *ever*
2. inside a transaction? (e.g., Objectify retries if it catches a `ConcurrentModificationException` but what happens if a transaction commit keeps failing?)

Thanks for any clarification anyone can give on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't care about the Key value (which may have been assigned, ie you had a null Long id), then you can ignore the return value.

Not directly in your question but needs to be mentioned: Using the automatic id generator inside of a transaction is dangerous and should not be done, because it's not an idempotent operation. It's possible that you may get a transaction retry even though the transaction succeeded, and the retry will create a new entity. Always assign ids outside of the transaction.

I will go further and say that you should not use automatic assignment of ids *at all*. Explicitly generate them with the allocator when you construct your POJOs.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. With regards to retries, I have some log entries like this: `com.googlecode.objectify.impl.TransactorNo transactNew: Optimistic concurrency failure for <class> (retrying): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: too much contention on these datastore entities. please try again.`. Does 'please try again' mean Objectify will automatically retry the transaction?  Or does it mean the transaction has _repeatedly_ failed, Objectify has given up?  Would the latter throw a RuntimeException?  (I'm expecting some contention, but working out the best way to handle it).

Comment: It's a warning and it means Objectify is retrying for you. You would get an exception thrown all the way out if Objectify gave up. That said, by default Objectify doesn't give up - it will retry until you hit the deadline (or you get some other exception).

Comment: Your statement: "Using the automatic id generator inside of a transaction is dangerous and should not be done" - is not entirely true. Create the objects outside the transaction and the id will be set only once.

Comment: You are mistaken. If ConcurrentModificationException is thrown, the id of the POJO will not be set. CME can be thrown even if a transaction succeeds. When Objectify retries, you will get a duplicate. All transactions must be idempotent.

Comment: @stickfigure I don't think I am. Let me try to explain in even though SO's comment formatting is not perfect.
' Entity e = new Entity(); new Transaction() { e.save()}.do();' the point is: No matter how many times the transaction runs the Id attr. is only autogenerated once see. https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities. So even if the transaction runs 100 times it will just "overwrite" the same id. Note that it is the transaction object that can be retried.

Comment: I don't understand the code snippet, but I assure you that if you generate an id *inside* of a transaction (with either the auto generator or the allocator), you will generate new ids every time the txn attempts to execute. If you want an idempotency guarantee, generate the id outside of a transaction. I've been told, however, that GAE is changing behavior so that CME is never thrown on a successful commit, which makes this less precarious. I don't know if/when that change became live.

Comment: @stickfigure You may be correct but then the documentation is incorrect in: "...If you use Long and save an entity with a null id, a numeric value will be generated for you...". Since on a transaction retry my entity Id is already set and therefore not null. Again note that I create the entity before entering the transaction so its the same instance in the retry.

Answer (score 1):

Saving the entities with one call will result in a single RPC, meaning that the window of transaction failure will be smaller (calling `.now()` twice is triggering two synchronous RPCs). Remember also that there is a throttle on writes to an entity group, so any pattern that causes more RPCs has a wider impact than just transaction elapsed time itself.

The result of save will always have a key, a failure would result in an exception (and in the context of a transaction, possibly a retry). So it isn't meaningful to use it as a status check. Its just useful if you want to know the key after you do a put.

Comment: Thanks - this helps clarify my understanding.